# Visual Studio generating overflow warning when working with two integers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, c++17, integer-overflow

I am working in Visual Studio Community 2019 and I am getting a C26451: Arithmetic Overflow warning when using the minus sign inside [] operator of a vector. My code:

```
std::vector<int> cx;
// code to fill cx

// iStrt and iCnst are constant iterators and pData is my data vector
for (int ii = 1; ii < cx.size(); ++ii) {
    if (cx[ii - 1] < 0) // C26451: Arithmetic Overflow
        iStrt = pData.cbegin();
    else
        iStrt = iCnst + cx[ii - 1]; // C26451: Arithmetic Overflow
}
```

The entire warning is:

> C26451: Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '-' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '-' to avoid overflow

Why is there a warning when all I am doing is a simple integer subtraction?

**Addition after comments:**

The entire function is too long and complicated to post here. The main job of the function is to translate the data points in a `std::vector<double> pData` to screen coordinates.
What I have posted above is more or less the same as below. The code below has more explanations. This is a basic part of my function, I think it should be reproducible.

```
void UPlot::plotData()
{
    // This vector contains indexes for data plotting
    // i.e. pData[cx[1]] - pData[cx[0]] will be plotted
    // in a single column of pixels
    std::vector<int> cx;

    // constant values:
    // w_ = width in pixels (e.g. 500)
    // lft_ = Start data index (e.g. 150)
    // rit_ = End data index (e.g. 10000)
    // xFact_ = (rit_ - lft_) / w_ i.e. translation factor
    for(int ii = 0; ii < (w_ + 1); ++ii)
        cx.push_back(round(lft_ + (ii * xFact_)));

    // since the difference between cx[ii] - cx[ii-1] is
    // required, cx has to be greater than 1
    if (cx.size() > 1) {
        iCnst = pData.cbegin();

        // iterate over cx and find out the number of data points
        // that will be plotted in a single column of pixels
        for (int ii = 1; ii < cx.size(); ++ii) {
            if (cx[ii] < 0)
                continue; // only +ve indexes can work
            else if (cx[ii - 1] >= pData.size())
                break; // reached end of pData
            else {
                // The condition in which pData values will be
                // translated into pixel values
                
                // find the starting iterator
                if (cx[ii - 1] < 0)
                    iStrt = pData.cbegin();
                else
                    iStrt = iCnst + cx[ii - 1];

                // Find the end iterator
                if (cx[ii] >= pData.size())
                    iStop = pData.cend();
                else
                    iStop = iCnst + cx[ii];

                /* ----- Rest of the code ----- */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also to note, before this I was using `QVector` instead of `std::vector` and I never had this warning with `QVector`.

Comment: a warning does not mean that your code **is** wrong. It just means that under certain circumstances it can be wrong, and the message explains why. If it does not apply in your case you have two options: Fix the code to silence the warning or ignore the warning

Comment: Unless you want to use negative indexes (which is possible but very seldom used) my recommendation is to always use `unsigned` types for array indexes.

Comment: On that note, replace `int ii` with `size_t ii`, it should make the warning go away.

Comment: You can also use an iterator loop instead of an index loop, and that way work around the warning.

Comment: *Or* (just to silence the warning) start `ii` from *zero* instead of `1`, so you don't have to do that arithmetic when indexing.

Comment: @idclev463035818 How can fix the code to silence it? I hate any warnings in my code
@Someprogrammerdude I have to start with 1 because I have to be able to check `ii - 1` value.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. I was about to write an answer, but I cannot reproduce all warnings you report

Comment: But if you start with `0` then you *don't need* to subtract `1`. You can use `ii` without change.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If the loop starts at `0` then the stop condition becomes `ii < cx.size() - 1`, which will trigger the next warning ;)

Comment: Who, what a horribly written error message. "casting the result" is wrong -- there are no casts in the code. And 4-byte vs. 8-byte isn't the issue. The issue is about converting a signed value to an unsigned value -- converting a negative value can lead to surprises.

Comment: Regarding that problem @idclev463035818, is there a good standard way to deal with such things; assuming of course that we need to use indices and can't use range based loops for example.

Comment: @Dirk yes of course there is a solution. My point was just that the naive way of fixing the one warning (as suggested by Some dude) introduces a different warning and I suppose if OP didn't know how to fix the first, they also don't know for the other

Comment: @idclev463035818 Could you share how to best do it in this case? I myself have similar issues at times when using sizes of vectors, so I would personally be interested in the "best" or standard way to set up the loop in such a case, so that it is both relatively save from errors and the compiler is happy even on strict settings.

Comment: @Dirk `ii + 1 < cs.size()` (unless `ii+1` is suspectible to overflow)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `const_iterator`, `std::prev` and `std::next`

```
std::vector<int> cx;
// code to fill cx

// Iterators for cx
std::vector<int>::const_iterator ix0;
std::vector<int>::const_iterator ix1;

ix1 = cx.cbegin();

for(ix0 = cx.cbegin(); ix0 != std::prev(cx.cend()); ++ix0){
    ix1 = std::next(ix1);
    if (*ix1 < 0)
        continue;
    else if (*ix0 >= pData.size())
        break;
    else {
        if (*ix0 < 0)
            iStrt = pData.cbegin();
        else
            iStrt = std::next(pData.cbegin(), *ix0);

        if (*ix1 >= pData.size())
            iStop = pData.cend();
        else
            iStop = std::next(pData.cbegin(), *ix1);
    }
}
```

I haven't tried the entire function yet. I will update if this doesn't work.